# SublimeText 3 Sublimelinter Pep257 only ignore D102 on __init__ methods?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

OK, so I am finally **annoyed** enough to ask this question.  I use Sublime Text 3 as my editor and I use Sublimelinter plugin with `Pep8` and `Pep257` with my python files.  When building a class, it is my interpretation that it is acceptable to document the `__init__` method for a class in the main class docstring. (*this is correct, right?*)  As such, is it possible to have sublimelinter only ignore error `D102: Missing docstring in public method` only for `__init__` methods?  I know I can make the warnings passive, my OCD just doesn't like seeing the warning icon in the gutter and I end up putting a dummy `"""See main dosctring."""` docstring in just to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, you can document `__init__` in the class docstring - see e.g. http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html. Have you made any attempt to configure `pep8`?

Comment: Having just checked [the docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pep257-nurdok/latest/pep257-nurdok.pdf), it seems like there will be no method to do this in the near future.  Searching the document for "\_\_init\_\_" illustrates a commitment to keep missing `__init__` method errors as a member of D102 instead of D105 otherwise specified for "magic" methods.  In order to fix the issue annoying you (and me), a new error code would have to be assigned just to `__init__` methods so that you could ignore them.  Perhaps it is worth submitting a change request.